# Prove a map is a covering map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X= \{(z,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 \vert y = z^3\}$, $Y = X \setminus \{0,0)\}$, and $\mathbb{C}^* = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. How do I show that the map $q: Y \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ of projection onto the second coordinate is a covering map and identify the fiber $q^{-1}(1)$. I know the definition of a covering map, I'm having trouble writing down neighborhood $U$ in $\mathbb{C}^*$ that is evenly covered by $q$, what is $q^{-1}(U)$ here? Is the fiber $q^{-1}(1)$ just the 3 element set $\{(1,1), (-1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2, 1), (−1/2-i\sqrt{3}/2,1)\}$?

Comment: Observe that, $x\mapsto x^3,x\in \Bbb C\backslash\{0\}$ is a $3$-fold covering map.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is the graph of the function $\mu_3 : \mathbb C  \to \mathbb C,\mu_3(z) = z^3$. Hence the map $H : \mathbb C \to X, H(z) = (z,\mu_3(z))$, is a homeomorphism. It restricts to a homeomorphism $h: \mathbb C^* \to X \setminus \{H(0) \} = Y$. It therefore suffices to show that $q \circ h : \mathbb C^* \to \mathbb C^*$ is a covering map. But we have $q \circ h = \mu_3^*$, where $\mu_3^*$ is the restriction of $\mu_3$.

The map $\phi : (0,\infty) \times S^1 \to  \mathbb C^*, \phi(r,w) = rw$, is a homeomorphisms (its inverse is $z \mapsto (\lvert z \rvert, z/\lvert z \rvert)$). For $k = 1,2,3$ the sets $U_k = \{ e^{it} \mid 2(k-1)\pi/3  < t < 2k\pi/3 \}$ are disjoint open subsets of $S^1$, thus the $W_k = \phi( (0,\infty) \times U_k)$ are disjoint open subsets of $\mathbb C^*$. They are mapped by $\mu_3^*$ homeomorphically onto $Z = \mathbb C^* \setminus \mathbb R_+$ which is open in $\mathbb C^*$. Similarly the $W'_k = e^{i\pi/3}W_k$ are disjoint open subsets of $\mathbb C^*$ which are mapped by $\mu_3^*$ homeomorphically onto $Z' = \mathbb C^* \setminus \mathbb R_-$. Since each $z \in \mathbb C^*$ has $Z$ or $Z'$ as an open neighborhood, we see that $\mu_3^*$ is a covering with three sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b\in \Bbb C^*$ and $a^3=b$. Then there is nbd $U$ of $a$ and nbd $V$ of $b$ such that, $f:U\to V$ defined by $f(x)=x^3,x\in U$ is a homeomorphism. This is because of the fact, the holomorphic map $z\mapsto z^3,z\in \Bbb C^*$ has non-vanishing derivative everywhere.

Now, $$q^{-1}(V)=\bigg((U\times V)\cap Y\bigg)\bigsqcup \bigg((\omega U\times V)\cap Y\bigg)\bigsqcup\bigg((\omega^2 U\times V)\cap Y\bigg),$$  and $(\omega^k U\times V)\cap Y=\{(\omega^kz,y):z\in U\}$ homeomorphic to $V$ for each $k=0,1,2$.